# How to check email is exist or not in node js by using sendgrid

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, email-validation

I want to check the signup email is valid or not. (Here "valid" means the email exists.) I think if I receive the result from the SendGrid mailer then I can see it. But when I send the message to the signup email the result was always successful even though the email doesn't exist. Below is my code and I always got the result as status 202, instead of getting an error.
I will be very appreciative if someone solve this problem or teach me another validation method.

```
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
require("dotenv").config();

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

const sendEmail = async (options) => {
  const msg = {
    from: process.env.FROM_EMAIL,
    to: options.email,
    subject: options.subject,
    text: options.message,
    html: options.html,
  };

  console.log(msg);
  try {
    let result = await sgMail.send(msg);
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("email sending error ==> ", err.response.body);
    return false;
  }
};

export { sendEmail };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sendgrid has a separate api for email validation. You can find it [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/managing-contacts/email-address-validation/).

Syntax for request and response can be found [here](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/email-address-validation/validate-an-email).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used this functionality as you said. I think it is good for checking the domain and some statistical analysis but it is not exactly correct. What I mean it can not extract fake email that is similar to real one.

Comment: You need to check field called "suggestion", it should have suggestions about mistyped emails. Here is an example https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/managing-contacts/email-address-validation/#suggestions-for-domain-typos